# Sending json to asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I have a controller with `Get` and `Save` methods. `GetData` method will send a JSON to front end. I did this following this blog.

http://johnnycode.com/2012/07/16/getting-json-from-asp-net-beautiful-good-bad-ugly/

Now I am not sure how to implement Save().
Since I am returning a JSON, I don't have a viewmodel.
UX side is handled by a different team.
So it would be helpful if anyone could tell me how to send back the JSON to the Save().

Currently my save is like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return this.View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    return new JsonNetResult() { Data = this.aggregatedUserAppSettings.GetAllUserAppSettings() };
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(JObject setting)
{
}
```

I expect that the setting variable should have a  value as `{{property1: value1},{property2: value2}}`

How should the front end pass the JSON for this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of your action method to a `JsonResult` then you can return whatever Json you need using an anonymous object:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(JObject setting)
{
    //logic to save here

    //use anonymous object to return whatever json you want here
    return Json( new {success = true, data = yourData} )
}
```